# Would using a NAS for backup in this case be any better than using an external drive?

Tags: windows, windows-10, backup, nas, synology

I'm fairly new to this, so maybe the whole premise is flawed, and there is a better way, but here goes.

I am using Windows 10 Home and I'd like to at least somewhat ensure the safety of my data by making periodic backups. On my desktop I have: 2x2TB drives + 6TB drive for data and 1TB SSD for system. I was thinking of getting a Synology NAS and 12TB drive to do a periodic, say once in one or two weeks, backup of the whole thing. I'm not talking any fancy "I just want to backup my important photos/music/documents", no, the whole thing as it is on the desktop data drives, plus ideally an image of the system SSD.

Yes, I know the old adage, that a mirror isn't a backup, but I'm trying to balance the budget and at least some sort of security. I'm not too worried about losing any recent data (thus the 1-2 weeks backup period), but I'd still hate to lose it all, be it by hardware failure or ransomware.

Now the questions stand:

1. Is that something that can be done on a Synology NAS (I was thinking of DiskStation DS218play)?
2. Is a NAS necessarily the best way to do this?

So far I've seen Synology having a boatload of apps for people who want to access their data from anywhere (i.e. use the NAS as a NAS) and do some of the fancy "important photos/music/documents" backup stuff.

Maybe a simple external drive would be better for the purpose. If so, can you recommend any app that'd keep track of changes made to the data since the last backup and then perform an increment (I guess) on the external?

Comment: I think you're asking too many different questions here. This community provides the best answers when you ask focused questions. It's hard to extract what your primary question is from that wall of text.

Comment: The elephant in the room steps up to the microphone: What OS are you using? If you are, for example, using macOS it comes with Apple’s Time Machine backup software that works well on most any external drive. A NAS is only worth using to share data across systems and devices.

Comment: I'm on WIn 10 Home.

Comment: NAS is over spending for a backup solution.

Comment: TLDR instead of a wall of text: What in your oppinion is the best way to do a periodic 1-2 week backup of cca 11TB spread across multiple local drives. On Win 10.

Comment: I will say only this, to avoid getting too far into opinion; the average lifespan of a good quality drive (3-5 year warrantee) running in a NAS is likely to far exceed the lifespan of a pre-packaged external disk. the reasons are mostly companies tend to use cheap disks when building prepackaged external drives, and because most people keep their NAS in a much safer place than they do their external disks (like not right on the edge of a desk/table and don't try to take them anywhere)

Comment: “What in your opinion is the best way…” There are as many different opinions here as there are users. So this question is pretty much off topic.

Comment: Hmm, I was thinking more a Seagate IronWolf, 3,5" - 12TB in an external box, rather than pre-packaged solution. But maybe that's not ideal due to it being a drive designed for NAS. IDK, that's why I'm asking for opinions. BTW thanks for the input so far.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I was just trying to repackage the question into TLDR. Yes, there are probably as many opinions as there are users, but I hope in the non-TLDR version, I specified pretty thoroughly, what my intent and constrains are. So what in that particular instance would you do?

Comment: I am backing up my drives to a Synology NAS box.  I purchased one, after Dropbox charges and rules got out of hand.  I am using it to backup most of my important documents and photos.  I can also access them from anywhere.  Then I shifted my GIT repos from my Dev machine to the NAS box.  Then I added drive backups.  I have a second one at my holiday home and I backup the local one to that.  The only drawback so far, is that backing up Windows drive is an issue as it keeps failing on many files and folders.  Otherwise I am happy with it.

Comment: Well, I use macOS and only use a 2TB SSD drive for system backups with Time Machine. So that is all I can add. 12TB in an external enclosure is way out of the scope of what I use backups for.